# Adding javascripts functions dynamically in mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, dynamic-programming

I'm creating a dynamic-form infrastructure. This infrastructure will get a certain XML which will include all of the form data, from the order in the page to validators.

The dynamic page may also contain fields which will require some sort of validation. The validation is not only trivial (such as "numeric"\"alphanumeric"), it might be something more complicated.

That's why I want to pass in my XML the validators javascripts.

When developing on traditional Web Application, it's simple to plant this code in the page header. But I don't know how to do so when using MVC3, since it's not a normal client-server application.

*It's important to explain - in my controller, I pass this dynamic-form class the xml file, it does all it should, and in the end, I plant the result in ViewBag.table.*

Anyone know how can I can plant the javascript code from the controller to view header?

**EDIT:**

I tried thw following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SetJScript", "MyPages")',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
        var myscript = document.createElement('script');
                    myscript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                    myscript.innerHTML = '$( document ).ready( function ( e ){' + result + '});';
                    document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(myscript);

            }
        });
```

and also:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SetJScript", "MyPages")',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                var myscript = document.createElement('script');
                myscript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                myscript.innerHTML = "function test() {alert('aa');}";
                document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(myscript);
            }
        });
```

or change the:

```
myscript.innerHTML = "function test() {alert('aa');}";
```

to:

```
myscript.innerHTML += "function test() {alert('aa');}";
```

so it will be added to the existing "$documnet.ready" function.
None of it worked.
I kept getting "Unknown error"

Thank you all.

Comment: You are still missing semicolomn after ajax function and you didnt close document.ready

Comment: (just forgot copying it from my code)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps..

```
    $(document).ready(function () { 

        $.ajax(
    { url: '@Url.Action("SetJScript", "MyPages")',
     type: 'POST',
     success:   function(result) 
    { var myscript = document.createElement('script');      
       myscript.setAttribute('type','text/javascript'); 
       myscript.innerHTML = 'function test() {alert("aa");}'; 
       document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(myscript); 
    } //end of success
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, I tried it. It falls on "myscript.innerHTML = ..." I can't tell what the error might be, since I get "Error: Unknown runtime error".

Comment: K. I modified the code. Check whether $('#myscriptcode').val() is correct.

Comment: Still didn't work. It seems it doesn't like the ".innerHTML". I tried to write the script text: myscript.innerHTML = "function test() {alert('aa');}". It still had the same "Unknown runtime error"

Comment: Can you plz post your entire script section?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SetJScript", "MyPages")',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (result) {
                    var myscript = document.createElement('script');
                    myscript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                    myscript.innerHTML = "function test() {alert('aa');}";
                    document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(myscript);
                }
            })


        });

Comment: I think you missed a semicolon after ajax call. Check my updated code

Comment: No. Still same error... I really think it just won't work with ".innerHTML = "... I also tried "append" and it didn't work, and "appendchild". None of those had worked...

Comment: <head> tag is there in your page, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it is on my page... I also debugged it and saw that the "result" did include a function (currently it's only an alert message). I'm working with mvc3, this code is in the head of my page view (not the _Layout).

Comment: "...and saw that the "result" did include a function.." ?

Comment: The result is what I get back from the function. On second thought, I also tried to write the function just as you wrote it, so this comment doesn't really change anything...

Comment: Can you plz update the question with the code you tried, so that others can check for the problem?